# Objective C: Problem with get-methods in class

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parameter-passing

I have some class:

```
@interface SearchBase : NSObject
{
    NSString *words;
NSMutableArray *resultsTitles;
NSMutableArray *resultsUrl;
NSMutableArray *flag;
}

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *words;

- (id) getTitleAtIndex:(int *)index;
- (id) getUrlAtIndex:(int *)index;
- (id) getFlagAtIndex:(int *)index;
@end

@implementation SearchBase
 - (id) initWithQuery:(NSString *)words 
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    self.words = words;
}
return self;
}
- (id) getTitleAtIndex:(int *)index
{
return [resultsTitles objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id) getUrlAtIndex:(int *)index
{
return [resultsUrl objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id) getFlagAtIndex:(int *)index
{
return [flag objectAtIndex:index];
}
@end
```

But when I'm trying to use some these get-methods in subclass, I see:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'getTitleAtIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast 
warning: passing argument 1 of 'getFlagAtIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: passing argument 1 of 'getUrlAtIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

And program isn't work correctly. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: FYI, Cocoa convention doesn't use a "`get`" prefix for such methods. Just use something like `titleAtIndex:` and `urlAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing **integer values** to your methods which is wrong because the functions declared by you accept only `integer pointer` not value that's the reason for having warning.and `objectAtIndex:` method accept only integer value not pointer so if you run, it could cause **crash** in your application.

The simplest solation would be changing the parameter type in your functions.

```
- (id) getTitleAtIndex:(int )index;
- (id) getUrlAtIndex:(int )index;
- (id) getFlagAtIndex:(int )index;
```

and function implementaion could be similar to below function.

```
- (id) getTitleAtIndex:(int )index
{
    if(index < [resultsTitles count] )
        return [resultsTitles objectAtIndex:index];
    else
       return nil;
}
```

Comment: as @shaggy says above, this is kind of wrong.. it should be - (id)titleAtIndex:(int)i; or - (void)getTitle:(NSString *) atIndex:(int)index;